# Customise Permalink Structure For Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I've installed the Custom Post Types UI plugin and have made a post type and taxonomy. When I click 'add new' to make a new post the slug always defaults to:-

https://domain.com/custom-post-type/post-name

I would like the permalink for posts to inlcude the heirachy of taxomonies to show something like this:-

http://domain.com/custom-post-type/taxomony/sub-taxomony/post-name

How would I achieve this?

Many thanks

Will

Answer (score 0):

What is the setting of your permalinks under settings/permalinks?
Have you tried using
Custom Structure: /%category%/%postname%/
?

Comment: My permalink structure is set to custom with the following structure `/%day%/%monthnum%/%year%/%post_id%/%author%/` I thought this only affects posts/pages (the default post types that WordPress uses). So does this setting affect custom post types too?

Comment: I think so. Maybe try this plugin which says it allows separate permalink structures for custom post types : https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: I have tried both of those and don't seem to be having any luck. I have a category called 'Entertainment' and a taxonomy called 'Gaming'. 

This is the structure I would like:-
https://domain.com/entertainment/gaming/post_name

However, with the following permalink structure:-
entertainment/%custom_taxonomy_slug%/%postname%/

the 'custom_taxonomy_slug' tag doesn't work.